# Как замапить значения колонки в датафрейме только те, которые есть в словаре map'а?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, map

Мы не создаём новую колонку, а всего лишь заменяем значения другими соответствующими значениями из словаря. `pandas.Series.map()` меняет нетронутые значение на `NaN`, чего делать не требуется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете передать в `map()` функцию, которая будет менять только те значения, которые есть в словаре.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([['apple',2],['orange',3],['banana',3]], columns=['fruit', 'quantity'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
    fruit  quantity
0   apple         2
1  orange         3
2  banana         3

In [4]: fruits_map = {'apple': 'APPLE', 'banana': 'BANANA'}

In [5]: df['fruit'].map(lambda x: fruits_map.get(x, x))
Out[5]: 
0     APPLE
1    orange
2    BANANA
Name: fruit, dtype: object
```

Comment: Отлично, элегантно! Спасибо, Андрей!

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html):

```
In [28]: df['fruit'] = df['fruit'].replace(fruits_map)

In [29]: df
Out[29]:
    fruit  quantity
0   APPLE         2
1  orange         3
2  BANANA         3
```

PS позаимствовал пример данных из ответа @Andrey

Comment: Вот он метод то). Максим, спасибо!